# R: How to preallocate a list of empty dataframes?

Tags: r

I can't find this anywhere, surprisingly.

Let's say I want a list of 3 empty 4 x 4 dataframes

I'd create my data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=4, ncol=4))
```

Then sure, I could do:

```
list(df, df, df)
```

But there must be a more elegant way. What is it?

Comment: `rep(list(df), 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `lapply` them into existence:

```r
lapply(1:4, function(x) df)
```

or `replicate`

```r
replicate(4, df, simplify = FALSE)
```

or `rep` them if you first wrap them in a `list`, as @rawr points out:

```
rep(list(df), 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a `for` loop

```
lst1 <- list()
for(i in 1:4) lst1 <- c(lst1, list(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R trick

```
Map("*",as.list(rep(1,3)),list(df))
```

Comment: would be nice if `Map("*", as.list(1:3), list(df))` appended the object n times for each element